# Почему нельзя использовать потоки повторно?

Tags: java, многопоточность, language-lawyer

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, но всё же... Почему нельзя переиспользовать потоки?

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Comment: а какой был бы выиграш по вашему если бы была такая возможность ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Переиспользование потоков не принесло бы ощутимых преимуществ. Наоборот, повторный запуск потоков создал бы неудобства для программистов:

1. Если поток можно запустить дважды, то его можно запустить дважды из нескольких потоков. При этом неясно нужно ли уведомлять потоки-клиенты о «двойственном» состоянии потока-субъекта.
2. Отслеживание состояния потока теряет смысл. Поток никогда не будет по-настоящему завершен, т.к. может перезапустить сам себя либо быть перезапущен другим потоком.

[Доступ к общим ресурсам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) — основная проблема в многопоточном программировании. Одноразовые потоки в Java проще для понимания, т.к. позволяют виртуальной машине взять на себя синхронизацию изменения состояния потоков.

Наверное можно привести и технические аргументы: виртуальная машина использует потоки операционной системы, для которых перезапуск может быть ограничен. Но упрощение клиентского кода само по себе является достаточно веским аргументом.

P.S. Переиспользовать можно объекты [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Достаточно реализовать интерфейс и создавать потоки по необходимости:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new MyRunnableObject();
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
//синхронизация внутреннего состояния MyRunnableObject по вкусу
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос совершенно не глупый. Просто вы подошли к поиску ответа на него слишком узко :) Потоки переиспользовать (ахтунг: именно переиспользовать, а не перезапускать) можно. Этот подход называется пул потоков: про него можно почитать [спеку от оракла](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) или [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/326146/)